# Vertical text in table cell

Tags: jquery, html, rotation

How do I properly set some of the table cell to display text vertically.

with some help in forums I came up this following idea: 
http://jsfiddle.net/hr4tkg9q/

I am using the following jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('td.rotate').css('height', $('td.rotate').width());
});
```

the problem is, it properly sets the vertical text in 1st column but not the second or third one. will appreciate if you can help.

Comment: Maybe you should give the vertical cells the height of the other cells width and the width of the other cells height?

Comment: I cannot specify the height. height depends on the size of the text

Answer (score -1):

try to rotate a div in your cell not the cell.

```
<tr>
 <td>    
  <div class='rotate'>
   G
  </div>
 </td>

 ....
```

UPDATE:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('tr').each( function() {
    $(this).find('td.rotate').css('height', $(this).find('div.rotate').width());
  });   
});
```

i think this will help you
try this
http://jsfiddle.net/hr4tkg9q/2/

Comment: I tried but the height is too small. the height of the cell should be as the size of the cell text: http://jsfiddle.net/hr4tkg9q/2/